# Override blur() CSS filter in Firefox with Stylus or Greasemonkey

Tags: css, firefox, blur, css-filters, stylish

How can I disable the [blur CSS filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur) in Firefox?

Test sites:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it's not pretty.

```
* {
    filter: blur(0px) !important;
}
```

Run in Stylus or similar.

It works, but will override all filters. For example, the hovering nav bar on wikimedia commons will stop working: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page

You can use this on sites that override blur by simply enabling this Stylus script, and disabling it when it is not needed.